Flutter Fat Arrow up and down
I am looking for these types of arrows. I checked in MdIcons, Icons, CuppertinoIcons.
Couldn't find them. Is it not available on those 3 icons packages ?

Where  can I find those icons ?
I resorted to those for now but I really want the fat icons
 return Row(
      // return Column(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _upVoteTapped(upVoted);
          },
          padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
          icon: Icon(
            upVoted
                ? CupertinoIcons.chevron_up_circle_fill
                : CupertinoIcons.chevron_up_circle,
            color: Colors.green,
            size: 40,
          ),
        ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Text(data.voteCount.toString()),
        ),
        Container(
          // color: Colors.green,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              _downVoteTapped(downVoted);
            },
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            icon: Icon(
              downVoted
                  ? CupertinoIcons.chevron_down_circle_fill
                  : CupertinoIcons.chevron_down_circle,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 40,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );


It have in FontAwesomeIcon But it didn't free so you can just use free svg icon from svgrepo download it and use it as a asset
here your icon :  https://www.svgrepo.com/svg/167030/up-arrow-hand-drawn-outline

Font Awesome for Flutter is free at https://pub.dev/packages/font_awesome_flutter

Get Font Awesome for Flutter from:
Font Awesome for Flutter
To use it:
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

In code, it's a direct replacement for Icon(Icons.name):
FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.name)

